# Is ‘having’ a participle or gerund in the prepositional phrase?

Tags: prepositional-phrases

Is ‘having’ a participle or gerund in the prepositional phrase ‘to having his own office’

*He is accustomed to having his own office.*

Comment: It's a gerund because it functions as a complement of a preposition. However, in *The Cambridge Grammar of The English Language* (Huddleston & Pullum, 2002), the distinction between present participle and gerund is considered unnecessary and rejected. They use a single compound term covering both, *gerund-participle*.

Comment: Trad grammar would consider it a gerund since it heads a clause that is complement to a preposition, i.e. where nouns typically occur. But as @user178049 says, modern grammar simply calls it a gerund-participle. It's much simpler and avoids the endless and pointless discussions about gerunds vs present participles. The most important thing is that it's a verb.

Comment: You can have a large swimming pool. *Swimming* is a verb that is being used as a noun. Here, you cannot have a large *having*. It does not function in the same way. In a swimming pool, it's a pool made for swimming. But in having an office, it's not an office made for having. Call it whatever you like, but if the mainstream apprehension of a gerund is a verb that acts as a noun, then this word does not qualify.

Comment: @JasonBassford  It's not the word "having" that marks it as a gerund, but the whole clause "having his own office". Trad grammar calls it a gerund because it heads a clause that is complement of a preposition. It could be replaced with the NP "He is accustomed to his own private office". Btw I would say that "swimming-pool" is a compound noun -- not a syntactic construction consisting of noun+modifier -- in the same way as "bathing-costume", "frying-pan", "chewing-gum" etc. are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

V+ing words function as nouns/adjectives. Certain words are inseparable from the particles ( prepositions/ adverbs)they take after them invariably. " Having " together with the other words refer to a state of owning or being a referral to a noun. One can view HAVING either as a complement or object of preposition TO. However, HAVING function as a gerund according to traditional concept.HAVING is here independent of the Preposition TO.  TO is a part of the adjective, "accustomed" and together they form the adjective phrase.