# Participle or Gerund when prepositions are present?

Tags: gerunds, prepositional-phrases, present-participles

a)  After hav**ing** the meal, she went shopping.

b)  On be**ing** told the party was cancelled, the girl burst into tears.

c)  While walk**ing**  along the street, Sandy answered.

Please, advise whether the **ing**-forms placed after prepositions act as Participle or Gerund.

I have always thought that it is gerund that comes after prepositions, but working on a grammar exercise that is devoted to participles, I felt doubt.

Comment: Have you done any research yourself?

Comment: It seems to be a textbook test on the non-finite clauses. He/she hasn't seemingly.

Comment: BillJ, yes, i have always thought that it is gerund that comes after prepositions, but working on a grammar exercise,  that is devoted to participles, i felt doubt. I will surely be seaching more now.

Comment: Traditional grammar calls them gerunds because the clauses they head function as complement to a preposition, a function typically performed by nouns.

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/192354/is-having-a-participle-or-gerund-in-the-prepositional-phrase  is a probable duplicate

Answer (score 0):

This is actually called a **[participle clause](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/intermediate-to-upper-intermediate/participle-clauses)** (you can read more about it by clicking on the hyperlink). Therefore, the verbs *having*, *being* and *walking* in your examples are a **participle**, the clause containing them (the clause before the mid-sentence comma) is called a *participle clause* as it is headed by a participle (in this case the participle clause is after prepositions and conjuctions; this is also included in the hyperlink in the last section of the article).

Hope this helped!

Comment: The British Council is wrong about this. In traditional grammar, _ing_ clauses functioning as complement of a preposition are gerunds, not present participles.